# How can I restart an Azure App Service slot from Python?

Tags: python, azure, web-applications

I would like to restart a slot in my Azure Web application from Python.

How can I do that? I couldn't find anything about this in the official Python API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/

A workaround is to use the REST API exposed by the web application, but that's not quite what I need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/restartslot

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `azure.mgmt.web` module to manage web.

And in the **WebAppsOperations** class, there are `restart` and `restart_slot` method.

Further more information, you could refer to this official doc: [restart_slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-web/azure.mgmt.web.v2019_08_01.operations.webappsoperations?view=azure-python#restart-slot-resource-group-name--name--slot--soft-restart-none--synchronous-none--custom-headers-none--raw-false----operation-config-). The description about this method is `Restarts an app (or deployment slot, if specified).`.

Suppose this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful. How would I perform authentication with my web app in order to be able to restart it?

Comment: You could use azure_active_directory module to do it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/msrestazure/msrestazure.azure_active_directory?view=azure-python